# Is it possible to set two adapters for single spinner in Android?

Tags: android

I want to set an array adapter, and cursor adapter, for one spinner. Is it possible?

Comment: No it's not. How would you propose that worked? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but you can take a look to commonsguy's [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge), an Adapter implementation that accept multiple adapters and merges them into one single Adapter that you can pass to your spinner, if that's what you are looking for...

Comment: i used two adapter arrayadapter and cursor adapter how i merge this two adapter and set this merge adapter for spinner

Comment: in the library page and package there is documentation. basically you install the library, then you construct the MergeAdapter, you call addAdapter method to add as many adapters as you need, and then you call spinner's setAdapter passing the mergeAdapter...